# How to explode a nested struct in a Apache Spark DataFrame using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have searched now a couple of hours through the net to find any hint about how to explode a nested `struct` in an Apache DataFrame using pyspark. For `array` and `map` types there exists the function `explode()` in `pyspark.sql.functions`, however for a `struct` type such a function is **not** available (would be a nice feature though).

This is my problem:

I have a DataFrame that looks the following:

```
newJSON = '{"level_instance_json":{"events":{"0":{"id":1,"visible":true},"1":{"id":2,"visible":true},"2":{"id":1,"visible":false},"3":{"id":2,"visible":false}}},"user_id":"a1"}'
newJSON2 = '{"level_instance_json":{"events":{"0":{"id":1,"visible":true},"1":{"id":2,"visible":true},"2":{"id":1,"visible":false},"3":{"id":2,"visible":false}}},"user_id":"b2"}'
dfJSON = spark.read.json( sc.parallelize( [newJSON, newJSON2] ) ) 
dfJSON.printSchema()
```

[image]

You see clearly the nested structure in the `level_instance_json` `struct`. Now what I want to have is all of these nested structures exploded such that there are for each numbered `struct` (i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`) a new row (numbered by `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`). So, all my variables are on the same level:

```
event_id | id | visible | user_id
0          1    true      a1
1          2    true      a1
2          1    false     a1
3          2    false     a1
0          1    true      b2
1          2    true      b2
2          1    false     b2
3          2    false     b2
```

It is probably first a kind of `exlode` and then something like `transpose` (from column to row). How can this be done?

For my final task I have to somehow loop through all the numbered structs and I assume that exploding the nested structures makes this more efficient. If you have other suggestions, feel free to tell. I appreciate any good advice here.

Comment: Please [don't upload pictures of code/date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) when asking your question. Instead, please try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) with a small sample of your dataframe and the desired output.

Comment: @pault I edited now my question and generated a reproducible example and the desired output. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.